# Connecting an Epilog Laser Printer to network

Tags: networking, router, printing, printer

I am trying to help someone connect an engraver to their network and I am having no luck, I know I'm missing something but I cannot figure it out. The setup:

CenturyLink Modem --> Apple Airport Extreme --> Apple Extender Box --> Another Apple Airport Extreme --> Dlink DGS 108 --> Two PCs (Win7 and Win10, two engraver printers.

Just to make sure from the Airport Extreme I have an Ethernet cable connected from this <--> port to the dlink slot 1, 2 and 3 are the PCs, the gigabit switch slots 5,6 for the printers.

I just want to connect one printer (epilog fusion) to the  Win 7 PC for now. I'm using crossover cables for the printers from the dlink as epilog told me I HAD to use them.

Someone previously came and tried to set up the printers, with no luck. This is what I see on the printer itself:

- IP address:  `192.168.0.5`
- Subnet is: `255.255.255.0`
- Gateway: `192.168.0.1`

The printer was setup when installed using this:

- LPR
- IP address `192.168.0.5`

When I type in `ipconfig` I get:

- Gateway is `192.168.0.1`  -- assuming this is the router its connected to
- IPV4 `192.168.0.19`

Looking at the settings I also see that DHCP is disabled? For the life of me I cannot find the printer let alone get a connection. The settings do not look right to me at all, at this point I'm lost. Any help would be great.

Comment: These are pretty specialised bits of kit, you may need to contact the manufacturer. When I had to set up lab equipment I installed a second NIC into the PCs.

Answer (score 1):

The way that Epilog recommends connecting the printer is to have it directly connected to a second NIC in the PC.  That is why they tell you to use a crossover cable.  However, it works perfectly fine to connect the printer to a hub or a switch.  In that case, you should use a regular, straight-through cable, and treat it just like any other node on the network.

Comment: easy enough. How about the settings I show for the printer etc, do those look correct?

Comment: Yes, the settings look OK.  Assuming you have the cabling done right, you should be able to ping 192.168.0.5 from any of the PC's on the same network.